# Make type showable.

Tags: haskell

How to make type Showable?

```
type InterpreterMonad  = StateT (Env, Env) (ErrorT String IO ) ()
```

Normally, I would type `deriving Show` but I have a `type` not `newtype` or `data`.

P.S. How to write above with `newtype`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the effect of type synonyms on instances of type classes? What does the TypeSynonymInstances pragma in GHC do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125674/what-is-the-effect-of-type-synonyms-on-instances-of-type-classes-what-does-the)

Comment: if you look at `StateT` it's basically a function and now you have the problem of making a function showable - take `id :: a -> a` for example - what should `show id` print?

Answer (score 4):

`type` creates a type synonym. If you want to create an instance, you must create it for the target of the type synonym – in this case, `StateT (Env, Env) (ErrorT String IO ) ()`. However, GHC can't derive a `Show` instance for `StateT` types because `StateT` is a wrapper around a function type and GHC can't derive `Show` for function types.

You could write a newtype as follows:

```
newtype InterpreterMonad = MkInterpreterMonad (StateT (Env, Env) (ErrorT String IO ) ())
```

but this won't allow you to derive `Show` either, since `InterpreterMonad` is now a wrapper around a wrapper around a function type.